# Google Chrome looks Dark/Grayed Out?

Tags: google-chrome

Has anyone noticed that all of a sudden (as of this morning) that Google Chrome looks different? My Chrome browser looks as if it's grayed out (colors are darker, almost a black-n-white look), and tab titles look lighter than usual, something is def not right, possibly caused by the latest update? Anyone else experiencing this?

I tried uninstalling/re-installing and it didn't work?

If nobody else is experiencing this I'll chalk it up to it being my computer and remove this question....

(All my other browsers work fine)

Chrome Version: Version 32.0.1700.76 m

OS: Windows 7

**UPDATE:**
Downgrading to version 31x fixed all of these problems, I'm guessing it had to do with an incompatibility issue with the chrome update and my current GC driver, as NVIDIA has been acting up lately....

Also note that the rendering of default `input` elements such as text, dropdown menus, and number inputs are rendering incorrectly, and sometimes you can't even see the content.

Ex:

[image]
Screenshots:

what it should look like:
[image]

What mine looks like:
[image]

Comment: can you include screenshot, plus add Chrome version and your OS.

Comment: added a few pics above

Comment: Have you checked your video cables? Try to disconnect and reconnect video cables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you've gone incognito?  It's darker.  Here is the main window sitting behind the incognito one to give you the color difference.

To get there click the click the three bars on the right to get this setup menu.

Comment: Yes, it sort of has that affect, but that's not the problem, I'm not in incognito mode, and there is no little "spy character" in the top left corner

Comment: How about any of these?  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/themes?hl=en

Comment: tried changing theme, no difference, rolled back to default, still see the above issues. i added some pics in the question

Comment: What happens if you re-install?

Comment: nothing, first thing i tried

Comment: The reinstall might not fully remove all configuration files.  You might have to do an uninstall and then also go delete the programs directory in Program Files.   . AND also delete any content in C:/Users/<your user name>/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome  (You might have to first enable access to AppData so you can do this).  BTW, what virus software are you using, and do you have a backup available?  And can you do a system restore?

Comment: I tried everything you mentioned except doing a system restore. I'll have to try that later today. thanks for the help tho, I can't find any info on this it seems i'm the only one lol

Comment: We all have stupid problems that occur from time to time.  Last week I had a directory I absolutely could not delete.  I heard of a computer professor who could not delete some widget from his desktop.  It's part of life in the bit lane.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get rid of this issue either. I had to rename the executable file for chrome to something else to get the old chrome back(chromer.exe). This worked and my chrome is back to normal. Subsequently, internet explorer stopped working, it will not load at all. I do not know if they are related to the same issue or not.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was my computer initially, so I restarted it but no change. I'm not sure what the problem is, but here's what I did.

I had to disable, then re-enable, my extensions, and just updated my chrome settings. Then I refreshed the pages while the settings page was still open and that worked. I'm not sure why, but it finally got rid of the graying. (I've never been this excited to see white backgrounds actually show up as white!)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I disabled Hardware acceleration in settings, and relaunched. It's like an on/off button for grey/white. (Under Setting > Advanced Options > System)

Answer (score 0):

For me [this Google answer](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/10689817?hl=en&msgid=22813253) solved the issue:

> Go to chrome://flags/, search for 'force color profile' and change the setting to sRGB. Happened with me as well and came across this fix on another thread. This worked like a charm

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me on Windows 10, with Chrome 66; same issue as OP.

I downgraded to earlier versions of Chrome, which fixed the problem, but auto update was in effect, and I couldn't block the filepath `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update`.

Another solution is to run the program in compatibility mode; Windows 8 worked for me:

[image: Google Chrome Properties, with compatibility mode checked]

Answer (score -1):

For me it was the Dark Reader extension. As soon as I disabled it all was back to normal.