# Chrome is not being rendered

Tags: google-chrome

Everything was working fine. Suddenly my chrome stop rendering its any window properly. When I open chrome browser, chrome app launcher, or its system tray icon either it opens a blank window with blank title bar or transparent window.

In browser window if I move my cursor to address bar location > type some site (however I cant see what I typed) > hits enter, title in taskbar icon gets changed. It means it is performing all operations other than rendering any window.

I was planning to uninstall it. But It doesn't render uninstall wizard windows too :(

What Can I do?

Comment: I modified chrome GPU settings for performance improvement some weeks ago. Can it cause problem?

Comment: Possibly related to this: http://superuser.com/questions/703181/google-chrome-looks-dark-grayed-out

Comment: Thanks @ElipticalView . I had seen that answer. But in my case, it is not even rending the display.

Comment: Is it only chrome, how about FireFox, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your PC in safe mode and try to disable GPU support. See if it helps.

Comment: it solved my problem. But is there any way to enable GPU features?